# Bijection from ellipse to real line

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $f(x,y) = \cfrac{y}{x + 1}$ is a bijection from the unit circle with its south pole removed to the real line. I'm trying to find a similar bijection from the ellipse $S = \{(x,y): x^2 + 2y^2  =1 \}$  to the real line. The problem is that I only proved the first bijection mechanically (by showing that $f^{-1}(a) = \left(\cfrac{1-a^2}{1+a^2}, \cfrac{2a}{1 + a^2} \right)$ was its inverse) and didn't derive any of the two formulas myself - so I don't know what the bijection is actually "saying" nor consequently how to adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an obvious bijection between the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and the ellipse $(z/a)^2+(w/b)^2=1$: $(z,w)=(ax,by)$. Composing that with the known bijection between the circle and line yields the desired result.